# pressure under a barrier in water

Tags: fluid-statics

It's known that pressure underwater is caused by the weight of water column above the point.

so the pressure at point 1 under the chair in the image is less than this at point 2

is that right?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if that is a chair then the pressure at 1 and 2 are exactly same, as said by pascal's law. However if 1 is inside a sealed rigid box(isolated system), then the pressures at 1 and 2 are different.

Comment: Thanks, But i don't understand why ??    and what do you mean by a sealed rigid box ??

Comment: One that is isolated from the surrounding water. Like a submarine filled with water